# 2 videos with DirectShow in c#

Tags: c#, directshow

I would like to have 2 video windows playing a (same file for now) video. As I'm still new to c# and DirectShow I'm having problems with this and haven't found any working examples for multi-video solutions. I can get it to work for 1 window from samples, and would like to know what else is required to get the 2nd window working. Do I need to create a separate filter for the 2nd one aswell, or just fiddling around with the handles is enough?

Comment: I got a small problem after toying with it alot. The 1st video goes into its place nicely ,but the second one just keeps poping up in the Active Movie Video Window. Do I need to add a 2nd IVideoWindow? If yes ,how should try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What problems are you facing for multi-video rendering ?

As far as I know, you need to create one graph per video stream you want to have rendered, i.e. one Source/(Transform)/Render chain per stream. I don't think using a single render filter and playing with the windows handles is going to work (but I may be mistaken).

If you need to play the same video file in two different windows, just connect a Smart Tee filter after your source filter (or after your decompression filters), and connect a render filter to each of the Smart Tee's output pins.

If you want an easy method to test Directshow graphs, use [GraphEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphEdit) (available in the DirectX SDK and in many other places on the Internet).

Comment: Yes apparently a single render filter is not enough,it only showed one of the videos in the window no matter what I did. Thank you very much for the suggestion,got it working using GraphEdit.